# Accuracy of barcode vs qrcode?

Tags: barcode, qr-code

I want to develop a supermarket application for checking and billing.

Should I use barcodes or qrcodes? Which will give better accuracy?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be: which of these barcodes is already on the products sold?

Comment: On the "ability to read" side, absolutely, since all scanners that I have worked with present the data as a string, no matter the source.  On the "ability to write" side, it gets a bit trickier as you have to consider things like how much data needs to be encoded and what will be the reading capabilities of the folks who receive the documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both will be accurate, the question is how much data do you need to store.  QR has much more capacity than something like 3of9 barcode.

Comment: which will be faster for detection?I know that there are ready made 
barcode scaner availabe in markets.Are qrcode scanners  avaiable in market?

Comment: I wish this answer also weighed in on which one is quicker/easier to **be processed / read**

Answer (score 7):

The biggest difference here is that a linear barcode (e.g. Code 3 of 9, UPC, EAN, etc.) and a 2-dimensional symbology (e.g. QRCode, DataMatrix, etc.) store data in very different ways.  A linear barcode can be read with a simple laser scanner, while most 2-D symbologies require an imager in order to be read.  In general, imagers can also read linear barcodes, but are also more expensive than laser scanners.

You will want to consider whether your customers may already have linear scanners only, or whether they would be willing to pay the premium for an imager in order to get the benefit of the extra data that can be encoded in the 2-D symbologies.